# How can I present more than one alert in an if statement in Swift UIKit?

Tags: swift

```
    func submit(_ answer: String) {
        let lowerAnswer = answer.lowercased()
        
        if answer.count == 0 {
            showErrorMessage(errorTitle: "No answer", errorMessage: "Please provide a valid answer")
            return
        }
        
        if isPossible(word: lowerAnswer) {
            if isOriginal(word: lowerAnswer) {
                if isReal(word: lowerAnswer) {
                    userWords.insert(answer, at: 0)
                    
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                    
                    return
                }
                
                showErrorMessage(errorTitle: "Word not recognised", errorMessage: "You can't just make them up, you know!")
                return
            }
            
            showErrorMessage(errorTitle: "This word is already used!", errorMessage: "New word is required!")
            return
        }
        
        guard let title = title?.lowercased() else { return }
        showErrorMessage(errorTitle: "Word not possible", errorMessage: "You can't spell that word from \(title)")
        return
    }
    
    func isPossible(word: String) -> Bool { // Will check if the user is able to formuate a word
        guard var tempWord = title?.lowercased() else { return false }
        
        for letter in word { // Loops through the word provided by the player by checking and adding each letter to "letter" loop constant [This will contain all the letter from that word]
            
            if let positon = tempWord.firstIndex(of: letter) { // Checks if the player's word comtains letters from the start word [from what the player need to create a new word]
                tempWord.remove(at: positon) // Removes the used letter from the start word, that letter will not exist anymore so the player will not be able to use it twice
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        
        return true
    }
    
    func isOriginal(word: String) -> Bool { // Will check for duplicate words if any
        return !userWords.contains(word) // If the word is new this method will return "true", if the word was used before this method will return "false"
    }
    
    func isReal(word: String) -> Bool { // Will check is the word is a real word [english]
        let checker = UITextChecker()
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: word.utf16.count)
        let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")
        
        
        if word.utf16.count < 3 {
            showErrorMessage(errorTitle: "Word to short", errorMessage: "Please provide a longer word")
            print("This word is to short!")
            return false
            
        } else if title?.utf16.count == word.utf16.count {
            // showErrorMessage(errorTitle: "Invalid answer", errorMessage: "You cannot submit the start word!")
            print("You can't submit the start word!")
            return false
        }
        
        return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound // if misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound [true = not a valid word]; if misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound [false = we have a valid word        
    }
    
    func showErrorMessage(errorTitle: String, errorMessage: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: errorTitle, message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

How can I present 3 alerts in "isReal" if statement?
I tried and the debug console is telling me this:

> 2021-04-05 23:25:37.577297+0100 Project5[4940:314069] [Presentation] Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fd15902ca00> on <UINavigationController: 0x7fd159822000> (from <Project5.ViewController: 0x7fd158d06210>) which is already presenting <UIAlertController: 0x7fd15b01ae00>.

Comment: why do you want to present three alerts? Can't you put all information into one?

Comment: Short answer: Yes, you **can** do that, but you **shouldn't**.

Comment: What does presenting 3 alerts mean?  You mean, presenting another alert after one has been dismissed?

Comment: I was thinking to give some feedback to users when they provide a word which has less than 3 letters and when they want to submit the start word. Is just an exercise I wanted to experiment this as I'm learning, just making some small apps at the moment from Paul Hudson's website. Thank guys for taking your time and coming back to me on this!

Comment: Yeah I know is definitely not a good practice for a real word app for sure!

Comment: @ElTomato yes I want to present another alert after one has finished, for the "isReal" if statement, this was my challenge to solve and I was thinking to show some feedback to users "Disallow answers that are shorter than three letters or are just our start word. For the three-letter check, the easiest thing to do is put a check into isReal() that returns false if the word length is under three letters. For the second part, just compare the start word against their input word and return false if they are the same."

Comment: I already return after that condition is hit to false is working fine but just wanted to present some alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an extension like this:

```
extension UIViewController {
    static func top() -> UIViewController {
        guard let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController else { fatalError("No view controller present in app?") }
        var result = rootViewController
        while let vc = result.presentedViewController, !vc.isBeingDismissed {
            result = vc
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Then, instead of just calling `present(alert, animated: true)`, you can call `UIViewController.top().present(alert, animated: true)`.
This will cause each additional alert to get presented on top of the previous alert. The user will have to dismiss all three alerts before they get back to your screen.

---

So the above answers your question, but I hope that once you see what it's like for the user to have to dismiss several alerts, you will reconsider your design and instead present a single alert with appropriate text for all the problems. Or find some other UI that handles this issue.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, yeah I was thinking that the user would be overwhelmed with all these alerts, I'm just learning at the moment doing some challenges on some study project on Paul Hudson's website, I was thinking that if I have those two conditions declared in "isReal()" method it would be great to show the appropriate feedback for users in this case would be just for exercise but I couldn't figure out how to show more alerts, I understood that I'm already presenting an alert in that if statement for "isReal". Thanks for taking your time and coming back to me! Helps a lot at this point.

Comment: Never used extensions before, yeah I know this is not good practice been think how could I show more alerts how users will know that they need to provide a longer word or they're not able to submit the start word from which is given after the view has loaded.

Comment: @Daniel.T  I have free different conditions in "isReal()" method, yeah I do agree to present just one alert but my where I'm stuck is that how one alert could cover 3 different conditions if the user does something which isn't right?

Comment: `if x || y || z { present Alert }`

Comment: T thanks a lot I will refactor my code, yeah is definitely not working out with those alerts on top of each other, would stress out an actual end user:)) if this app was in live.